# Angular 2/5 componant interaction

Tags: angular

I have a guard-service which should change the member of my app.componant.
For that i created a setter at app.componant. This setter should executed by guard-service. I wanted to realize that by Input and Output.

```
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {Injectable, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    @Input() appc: AppComponent;                         
    canActivate(): boolean {
        if(!online) {                                    //if status isn't online
            this.router.navigate(['loginEmail']);        //go to loginpage
            this.appc.changeHeaderEnable(false);         //change value
            return false;
        }
        this.appc.changeHeaderEnable(true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If that shoould work i need the method changeHeaderEnable() in my AppComponant with @Output() as decorator:

```
import { Component, Injectable, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppComponent {
  headerEnabled = true;
  @Output()
  changeHeaderEnable(b: boolean) {
      this.headerEnabled = b;
  }
}
```

I reduced both components to the important content. 
Now i expect that everytime i link to a different route which has AuthGuardService as a guard, canActivate() should executed. But everytime i link to another router, i get following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeHeaderEnable' of undefined

Why is changeHeaderEnable undefined in my guard service? What did i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The decorators @Input and @Output are used for property binding between a Parent and Child component. You can not use them in your service as you have done. They are dependent upon change detection which is only available to components and directives.

Honestly, there is a lot going wrong in the code provided. I see you also decorated your app.component with @Injectable instead of @Component which is another big issue. By default all components (and directives) are injectable.

I would recommend completing the Angular tutorial if you haven't already:
[Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I´m still on it and i need this part for the application which i build together with the tutorial (no application for production). So there is no way to let these both components communicate?

Comment: only for understanding. Is the issue that i try to communicate from child to parent?

Comment: The way you have declared your classes they are not Components, they both are a Service. There is no issue using Input bindng to communicate from Parent to Child Component, nor is there an issue using Output binding to communicate from Child to Parent Component. Your issue is you have declared two services, not components.